# set margin from getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had created a `fixed` element that will always show on the top of the page.

I want to make the element below it have the same `margin-top` as the height of the `fixed` element so it won't overlay the other element.

But the problem is, it didn't work on `resize`.

HTML

```
<body>
   <div class="fixedEl">
      
   </div>
   <div class="otherEl">
      
   </div>
</body?
```

CSS

```
.fixedEl{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

JS

```
const fixedEl = document.querySelector(".fixedEl");
const height = notif.getBoundingClientRect().height;
const otherEl = document.querySelector(".otherEl");

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  otherEl.style.marginTop = `${height}px`;
});
```

Is there any problem with my code? Appreciate any kinda help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works fine. However the resize event is only fired when you resize, but not automatically when the site loads. I added that as you can see below.

```js
const fixedEl = document.querySelector(".fixedEl");
// Changed from notif to fixedEl
const otherEl = document.querySelector(".otherEl");
let height = fixedEl.getBoundingClientRect().height;
// We have no resize at the beginning, so we init the height
otherEl.style.marginTop = `${height}px`;

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
  height = fixedEl.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  otherEl.style.marginTop = `${height}px`;
});
```

```css
.fixedEl{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  border: 1px gray solid;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="fixedEl">
      foo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo barfoo bar
   </div>
   <div class="otherEl">
      bar
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: the margin didn't change dynamically when resizing

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate the height inside the resize listener should the element height change on smaller widths.

In the example below, resize the screen so the boxes wrap to the second line, and see how `otherEl`'s margin top automatically adjusts.

```js
const fixedEl = document.querySelector(".fixedEl");

const otherEl = document.querySelector(".otherEl");

window.addEventListener("resize", adjust);

function adjust() {
  const height = fixedEl.getBoundingClientRect().height;
  otherEl.style.marginTop = `${height}px`;
}
adjust();
```

```css
.fixedEl {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* below is for demonstration purposes */
.block {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.fixedEl {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fixedEl">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="otherEl">
    b
  </div>
```

Comment: the margin didn't change dynamically when resizing

Comment: @itsMe Have you tried running the snippet? It works there.